# What options are available for remote control of a Windows 10 PC over LAN?

Tags: wireless-networking, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, remote

I'm trying to remotely control a PC over a distance of about 40 feet (12 meters). I need two monitors, a keyboard, a mouse, and optionally a free USB for other peripherals. I have the extra DisplayPorts for the monitors if needed, as well as the extra USB ports. Gigabit LAN is also available as well as Gigabit WIFI.

The most important factor is price, and secondly is Windows / Linux cross-compatibility. The Monitors, keyboard and mouse are already acquired, and are not a factor in cost.

Some solutions that I came up with are:

- RDP LAN box
- USB + USB repeaters.
- DisplayPort + DisplayPort repeaters.
- USB over WIFI (Exists?)
- Display over WIFI (Exists?)
  However, if there are additional solutions, I'm open to suggestion.

What options exist for controlling and displaying the PC from this distance? Do the solutions that I list exist?

Comment: I do that here (15 meters) with Windows 10 machines using RDP and also using Radmin Server. Both work well.

Comment: You can use Microsoft Remote Desktop app or mstsc to remote connect from windows to Linux. If you would like to remote from Linux to Windows, you can use TeamViewer, Remmina, TigerVNC and so on. https://www.tecmint.com/best-remote-linux-desktop-sharing-software/